# giving preexisting texture to fbo to draw on it

Tags: opengl, textures, rendering, framebuffer

I wanted to know if it's possible to give a non NULL texture to a frame buffer to render on it. I mean just drawing on it so it will become the background of the final texture.

From what I have tried it just keep the texture I give and render it directly, there's no drawing on it ( as if the drawing part have been useless).
If i give a NULL texture the drawing is done.

So i wanted to know if it's possible, am i just doing it wrongly?

all example of use of fbo i've seen only show NULL texture sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not as common as the use case where content in an FBO attachment is rendered from scratch. That's why you won't find as many examples.

It's still perfectly legal, though, and should work. The only difference should really be that you don't call `glClear()` after attaching the texture to the FBO, and starting to render.

One case where you'll have to be careful is if you use depth buffering for the rendering you want to do on top of the original texture content. In this case, you will of course need a depth buffer attachment (which is typically a renderbuffer) in your FBO, as usual. In this case, you will need to clear your depth buffer, but *not* the color buffer, before starting to render:

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Well I havent been able to pass the texture to the fbo. But you gave me an idea. I first draw a basic quad with the texture on it then i clear the depth buffer. And continue to draw. Works well.